# Change enum schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I created schema `webapp` with tables and one column is depending on enum `enum_app_type`. But by accident I created this enum in public schema and fill db with data. Is there a way now to chane this webapp column to use `webapp.enum_app_type` instead of `public.enum_app_type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ALTER TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html) for that:

```
ALTER TYPE public.enum_app_type SET SCHEMA webapp;
```

Comment: That works perfectly and automatically updated enum references. Great, thanks